# How to perform UNION ALL on same CTE expression in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, union-all

I have created CTEs in initially then select query with union operation as I want duplicate rows.

```
with a as (select emp_name,empdept from emp)
 select * from a
union all
with a as (select emp_name,empdept from emp)
select * from a
```

I am getting an error ** syntax error at or near "WITH" **

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where you need to enclose each query of the UNION with parentheses:

```
(
  with a as (select emp_name,empdept from emp)
  select * from a
)
union all
(
  with a as (select emp_name,empdept from emp)
  select * from a
)
```

But why repeat the CTE?

```
with a as (
  select emp_name,empdept from emp
)
select * from a
union all
select * from a
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa48ec7aec9fe851efdca6c33feb7ae6)

---

If you have two different queries in the two CTEs, you can still do it like this:

```
with a as (
  select emp_name,empdept from emp1
), b as (
  select emp_name,empdept from emp2
)
select * from a
union all
select * from b
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e022733a401ef3a0af5f0a9c6b096fec)

Comment: If i am not repeating CTE it is giving me an error

Comment: @anukritikulshrestha [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa48ec7aec9fe851efdca6c33feb7ae6)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but the following should work

Let's create the table and insert some rows

```
create table emp (emp_name varchar,empdept int);
insert into emp values ('Pippo',1000);
insert into emp values ('Pluto',3000);
insert into emp values ('Franco',4000);
```

Now the query

```
with a as (select emp_name,empdept from emp),
b as (select emp_name,empdept from emp)
select * from a
union all
select * from b;
```

Result

```
 emp_name | empdept 
----------+---------
 Pippo    |    1000
 Pluto    |    3000
 Franco   |    4000
 Pippo    |    1000
 Pluto    |    3000
 Franco   |    4000
(6 rows)
```